# Redirect http to https appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, https, auth0

I have deployed an app in gcloud appengine. The main site is secured through a google managed certificate in app engine. However, after the authentication through [auth0](https://auth0.com/), the redirected url reviewresponse.beratics.com/dashboard is no more http secured although it has a certificate. That means I can change the url manually to https://reviewresponse.beratics.com/dashboard and it works. But it does not work automatically. What can I do, where is the problem? I have implemented pyopenssl and other measures such as talisman in python but the problem still persists. The backend is in flash, the app is on gcloud appengine flexible environment and the site is wordpress managed. The authentication to app works through auth0. All the callback Urls at Auth0 are with https. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As a possible workaround, GCE VM's [allows](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) custom firewall rules without any load balancer in front of them, in other words, you can use a GCE VM as a "proxy" setting a static IP blocking traffic over port 80 to then redirect to App Engine.

Also, I found this feature [Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/154529044), as a kind recommendation you can start it in order that you receive further information about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, but App Engine has a `secure` flag in the app.yaml config which you can set to `always` which will redirect all http traffic to https. The details of this you can find here 
[Google Cloud app.yaml ref](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) CTRL+F for 'secure'

Comment: This solution is for App engine Standard, @hurricane is using Flexible :)